# Merging two lists into one to create a phrase

Tags: python, list

Trying to accomplish something along the lines of the output being:

```
The first month is January. Happy New Year!
The second month is Feburary. Happy Valentine's Day!
...
The twelfth month is December. Merry Christmas!
```

Here is what I have so far, but I don't know how to merge the two lists to where they match up without using an "if-then" statement.

```
Months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

Greetings = ['Happy New Year!', 'Happy Valentines Day!', 'Happy St. Patrick Day!', 'Happy Easter!', 'Happy Memorial Day!', 'Happy Juneteenth!', 'Happy July Fourth!', 'Happy Senior Citizens Day!', 'Happy Labor Day!', 'Happy Halloween!', 'Happy Thanksgiving!', 'Merry Christmas!']
```

My current python is... (This kinda work's but is using an if-then (I think)

```
Months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
for x, value in enumerate(Months, 1):
    print(x, value)
    if x == 1: print("Happy New Year!")
    if x == 2: print("Happy Valentines Day!")
    if x == 3: print("Happy St. Patrick's Day!")
    if x == 5: print("Happy Memorial Day!")
    if x == 6: print("Happy July 4th!")
    if x == 9: print("Happy Labor Day!")
    if x == 10: print("Happy Halloween!")
    if x == 11: print("Happy Thanksgiving!")
    if x == 12: print("Merry Christmas!")
```

Comment: use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), also since you use enumerate you could have figured out that you can use indexes, but use `zip`

Comment: Can you please explain with examples? I am brand new into programming.

Answer (score 4):

With `zip`:

```
for m, g in zip(Months, Greetings):
    print(f"The month is {m}. {g}")
```

If you also want to print "nth", you can use a third list like:

```
nth = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelfth"]

for n, m, g in zip(nth, Months, Greetings):
    print(f"The {n} month is {m}. {g}")
```

Comment: Holy crap that worked! Life saver! Is there a way to break down what happened in "English". I have no clue what the zip is? Let alone the "f"The month is {m}.{g}"

Comment: Look at the official documentation for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

Comment: You are the best! Extremely fast and helpful. I wasn't expecting such a quick response. If I could be-friend you I would've done so! Thanks for the help so much once again, to me you are special lol!

Comment: Haha, happy to help!